# How to determine unknown socket options?

Tags: c, tcp, shared-libraries, reverse-engineering, ida

While reverse engineering a so library designed for android, I saw following code lines for a tcp connection.

```
int v28[2];
v28[1] = 0;
v28[0] = 10;

setsockopt(socket_ref, 1, 21, v28, 8);
setsockopt(socket_ref, 1, 20, v28, 8);
```

Second parameter defines level as SOL_SOCKET. But option values 20 and 21 is unknown. Can someone explain what is going on?

(I read many documentations from different websites with hoping to find those options. But I didn't find any documentation that explains options 20 and 21.)

Comment: Maybe [this](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/tools/include/uapi/asm-generic/socket.h#L9) helps...

Comment: I'm really sorry about wasting your time. Seems like somehow I was searching wrongly.

Comment: No need to be sorry. No one said it would be trivial to find that. Especially as these headers might vary between implementations it might take some longer searching to get what you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely won't find documentation on what those specific codes map to, as that's an implementation detail of your environment.  What you can do is search the system header files where `SOL_SOCKET` is defined and see if you can find the matching options.

For example, on my CentOS 7 machine, I searched for the defintion of the `SOL_SOCKET` level:

```
[dbush@db-centos7 ~]$ grep -r SOL_SOCKET /usr/include
/usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h:#define SOL_SOCKET    1
/usr/include/linux/atm.h: * SOL_SOCKET is 0xFFFF, so that's a bit of a problem
/usr/include/linux/dn.h: * DNPROTO_NSP can't be the same as SOL_SOCKET,
```

Where I found it in /usr/include/asm-generic/socket.h.  Looking at this file, I found this:

```c
/* For setsockopt(2) */
#define SOL_SOCKET  1

#define SO_DEBUG    1
#define SO_REUSEADDR    2
#define SO_TYPE     3
#define SO_ERROR    4
#define SO_DONTROUTE    5
#define SO_BROADCAST    6
#define SO_SNDBUF   7
#define SO_RCVBUF   8
#define SO_SNDBUFFORCE  32
#define SO_RCVBUFFORCE  33
#define SO_KEEPALIVE    9
#define SO_OOBINLINE    10
#define SO_NO_CHECK 11
#define SO_PRIORITY 12
#define SO_LINGER   13
#define SO_BSDCOMPAT    14
#define SO_REUSEPORT    15
#ifndef SO_PASSCRED /* powerpc only differs in these */
#define SO_PASSCRED 16
#define SO_PEERCRED 17
#define SO_RCVLOWAT 18
#define SO_SNDLOWAT 19
#define SO_RCVTIMEO 20
#define SO_SNDTIMEO 21
#endif
```

So, at least on my system, options 20 and 21 are `SO_RCVTIMEO` and `SO_SNDTIMEO` respectively.  These may differ on your system, so search the header files to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

We also describe the  `fcntl`  function, because it is the  POSIX  way to set a socket for nonblocking I/O, signal-driven I/O, and to set the owner of a socket. We save the `ioctl`  function for Chapter 17.

| level | optname | get | set | Description | Flag | Datatype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SOL_SOCKET | SO_BROADCAST | • | • | Permit sending of broadcast datagrams | • | int |
|  | SO_DEBUG | • | • | Enable debug tracing | • | int |
|  | SO_DONTROUTE | • | • | Bypass routing table lookup | • | int |
|  | SO_ERROR | • |  | Get pending error and clear |  | int |
|  | SO_KEEPALIVE | • | • | Periodically test if connection still alive | • | int |
|  | SO_LINGER | • | • | Linger on close if data to send |  | linger{} |
|  | SO_OOBINLINE | • | • | Leave received out-of-band data inline | • | int |
|  | SO_RCVBUF | • | • | Receive buffer size |  | int |
|  | SO_SNDBUF | • | • | Send buffer size |  | int |
|  | SO_RCVLOWAT | • | • | Receive buffer low-water mark |  | int |
|  | SO_SNDLOWAT | • | • | Send buffer low-water mark |  | int |
|  | SO_RCVTIMEO | • | • | Receive timeout |  | timeval{} |
|  | SO_SNDTIMEO | • | • | Send timeout |  | timeval{} |
|  | SO_REUSEADDR | • | • | Allow local address reuse | • | int |
|  | SO_REUSEPORT | • | • | Allow local port reuse | • | int |
|  | SO_TYPE | • |  | Get socket type |  | int |
|  | SO_USELOOPBACK | • | • | Routing socket gets copy of what it sends | • | int |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| IPPROTO_IP | IP_HDRINCL | • | • | IP header included with data | • | int |
|  | IP_OPTIONS | • | • | IP header options |  | (see text) |
|  | IP_RECVDSTADDR | • | • | Return destination IP address | • | int |
|  | IP_RECVIF | • | • | Return received interface index | • | int |
|  | IP_TOS | • | • | Type-of-service and precedence |  | int |
|  | IP_TTL | • | • | TTL |  | int |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | IP_MULTICAST_IF | • | • | Specify outgoing interface |  | in_addr{} |
|  | IP_MULTICAST_TTL | • | • | Specify outgoing TTL |  | u_char |
|  | IP_MULTICAST_LOOP | • | • | Specify loopback |  | u_char |
|  | `IP_{ADD,DROP}_MEMBERSHIP` |  | • | Join or leave multicast group |  | ip_mreq{} |
|  | `IP_{BLOCK,UNBLOCK}_SOURCE` |  | • | Block or unblock multicast source |  | ip_mreq_source{} |
|  | `IP_{ADD,DROP}_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP` |  | • | Join or leave source-specific multicast |  | ip_mreq_source{} |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| IPPROTO_ICMPV6 | ICMP6_FILTER | • | • | Specify ICMPv6 message types to pass |  | icmp6_filter{} |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| IPPROTO_IPV6 | IPV6_CHECKSUM | • | • | Offset of checksum field for raw sockets |  | int |
|  | IPV6_DONTFRAG | • | • | Drop instead of fragment large packets | • | int |
|  | IPV6_NEXTHOP | • | • | Specify next-hop address |  | sockaddr_in6{} |
|  | IPV6_PATHMTU | • |  | Retrieve current path MTU |  | ip6_mtuinfo{} |
|  | IPV6_RECVDSTOPTS | • | • | Receive destination options | • | int |
|  | IPV6_RECVHOPLIMIT | • | • | Receive unicast hop limit | • | int |
|  | IPV6_RECVHOPOPTS | • | • | Receive hop-by-hop options | • | int |
|  | IPV6_RECVPATHMTU | • | • | Receive path MTU | • | int |
|  | IPV6_RECVPKTINFO | • | • | Receive packet information | • | int |
|  | IPV6_RECVRTHDR | • | • | Receive source route | • | int |
|  | IPV6_RECVTCLASS | • | • | Receive traffic class | • | int |
|  | IPV6_UNICAST_HOPS | • | • | Default unicast hop limit |  | int |
|  | IPV6_USE_MIN_MTU | • | • | Use minimum MTU | • | int |
|  | IPV6_V6ONLY | • | • | Disable v4 compatibility | • | int |
|  | IPV6_XXX | • | • | Sticky ancillary data |  | (see text) |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | IPV6_MULTICAST_IF | • | • | Specify outgoing interface |  | u_int |
|  | IPV6_MULTICAST_HOPS | • | • | Specify outgoing hop limit |  | int |
|  | IPV6_MULTICAST_LOOP | • | • | Specify loopback | • | u_int |
|  | IPV6_JOIN_GROUP |  | • | Join multicast group |  | ipv6_mreq{} |
|  | IPV6_LEAVE_GROUP |  | • | Leave multicast group |  | ipv6_mreq{} |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| IPPROTO_IP or IPPROTO_IPV6 | MCAST_JOIN_GROUP |  | • | Join multicast group |  | group_req{} |
|  | MCAST_LEAVE_GROUP |  | • | Leave multicast group |  | group_source_req{} |
|  | MCAST_BLOCK_SOURCE |  | • | Block multicast source |  | group_source_req{} |
|  | `MCAST_UNBLOCK_SOURCE` |  | • | Unblock multicast source |  | group_source_req{} |
|  | `MCAST_JOIN_SOURCE_GROUP` |  | • | Join source-specific multicast |  | group_source_req{} |
|  | `MCAST_LEAVE_SOURCE_GROUP` |  | • | Leave source-specific multicast |  | group_source_req{} |

Figure 7.1  Summary of socket and IP-layer socket options for  getsockopt  and  setsockopt .

| level | optname | get | set | Description | Flag | Datatype |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| IPPROTO_TCP | TCP_MAXSEG | • | • | TCP maximum segment size |  | int |
|  | TCP_NODELAY | • | • | Disable Nagle algorithm | • | int |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| IPPROTO_SCTP | SCTP_ADAPTION_LAYER | • | • | Adaption layer indication |  | sctp_setadaption{} |
|  | SCTP_ASSOCINFO | † | • | Examine and set association info |  | sctp_assocparams{} |
|  | SCTP_AUTOCLOSE | • | • | Autoclose operation |  | int |
|  | SCTP_DEFAULT_SEND_PARAM | • | • | Default send parameters |  | sctp_sndrcvinfo{} |
|  | SCTP_DISABLE_FRAGMENTS | • | • | SCTP fragmentation | • | int |
|  | SCTP_EVENTS | • | • | Notification events of interest |  | `sctp_event_subscribe{}` |
|  | `SCTP_GET_PEER_ADDR_INFO` | † |  | Retrieve peer address status |  | sctp_paddrinfo{} |
|  | `SCTP_I_WANT_MAPPED_V4_ADDR` | • | • | Mapped v4 addresses | • | int |
|  | SCTP_INITMSG | • | • | Default INIT parameters |  | sctp_initmsg{} |
|  | SCTP_MAXBURST | • | • | Maximum burst size |  | int |
|  | SCTP_MAXSEG | • | • | Maximum fragmentation size |  | int |
|  | SCTP_NODELAY | • | • | Disable Nagle algorithm | • | int |
|  | SCTP_PEER_ADDR_PARAMS | † | • | Peer address parameters |  | sctp_paddrparams{} |
|  | SCTP_PRIMARY_ADDR | † | • | Primary destination address |  | sctp_setprim{} |
|  | SCTP_RTOINFO | † | • | RT O information |  | sctp_rtoinfo{} |
|  | `SCTP_SET_PEER_PRIMARY_ADDR` |  | • | Peer primary destination address |  | sctp_setpeerprim{} |
|  | SCTP_STATUS | † |  | Get association status |  | sctp_status{} |

Figure 7.2  Summary of transport-layer socket options.